# c# Forms Combobox SelectionChangeCommited triggered on TabControl Tab change

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

I have a tab control with three tabs. The middle tab has a combobox which is bound to a database for its content. I would like to update other text fields based on the users selection from the combobox.

The problem i having is that in order to do that I used `SelectionChangeCommited` Event which fires as it should however, it also fires when I change Tab why is that and how can i make it stop?

Comment: don't add "Hi - Thanks" to your questions in the future ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `SelectedIndexChanged` event for the combobox.

```
    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer however i noticed something else, if i close the form (using the litle x in the top right) it also fires this event. Any reason why ?

Comment: Perhaps because when it's releasing resource, it clears the items list in the comboBox, which triggers that event?  That is my best guess.

Comment: Is there anyway to stop it from firing the event then ?

Comment: Hmm..I'm not sure what the best way would be.  You could try deregistering for the SelectedIndexChanged event by overriding the OnClosing method.  You deregister for the event the same way you register for it, except use a '-=' instead of a '+='.

Comment: Out of interest is there a way to do it with (sender== ??). I gave that a shot but no luck, seems to fire as it was ment to and not via some other sender.

Answer (score 0):

The Solution to the fireing of the EVENT when the form is closed which also triggers the SelectedValueChanged is to use **SelectionChangeCommited** instead.